# Drawing a pyramid with vertex and face arrays in openGL

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, shapes

I've been going through graphic tutorials and found one for a cube that draws it with 2 2D arrays, one is a 8 x 3 to store vertices and another is a 6 by 4 to store the faces, with the numbers being the vertices that make up those faces.

The arrays are initialized like this
[image: The arrays are initialized like this]

And then the cube is drawn by doing this:

```
void draw_face(int i)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3fv(vertex[face[i][0]]);
    glVertex3fv(vertex[face[i][1]]);
    glVertex3fv(vertex[face[i][2]]);
    glVertex3fv(vertex[face[i][3]]);
    glEnd();
}

//A cube consists of 6 faces
void  cube()
{
    for (int I =0 ; i<6; i++) 
        draw_face(i);
}
```

My question is how do I go about applying this to drawing a pyramid? I get that you can draw the bottom the same way but the 4 triangle faces have me confused, I would like to know how to initialize those arrays for a Triangle, I just can't really grasp how to initialize the vertices and faces for something that inst a cube, is there a easy way to approach this?

Comment: Just for the records: You should start learning modern OpenGL. And it seems you just want to draw the edges of whatever you have. Why not store these edges (pairs of two vertices) instead of faces.

Comment: The code above uses `GL_LINE_LOOP`. When drawing any shape you should be storing vertices into your array or vector as a vec3. As for your 3D object you want to triangulate its surface area into a mesh of triangles where each vertice is stored into an array buffer in a specific order. Winding order of your triangles are important if `GL back face culling is on`. You would then want to render the triangles via `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`. Just as `BDL` stated you should be learning modern OpenGL and stay away from Legacy OpenGL v1.0.